# Why same code in Kaggle with p100(16gb) is much faster than the my local 3090? Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-processing

When running the same code in kaggle (p100 16gb) and my local machine 3090(24gb) in tensorflow, the kaggle training speed is much faster than my local machine. I thought maybe its data processing problem, and this is the code. Any suggestions?

This is the code for my data processing.

```
def decode_and_resize(img_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [image_size,image_size])
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img

def process_input(img_path,img_label):
    return decode_and_resize(img_path), img_label

def make_datasets(images,labels):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,labels))
    # dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size)
    # dataset = dataset.map(process_input,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    # dataset = dataset.batch(bs).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

```
def prepare_dataset():
    # create dict
    unlabel_train_path_list = all_image_paths[:unlabeled_dataset_size]
    unlabel_train_label_list = all_image_labels[:unlabeled_dataset_size]
    unlabel_train_dict = dict(zip(unlabel_train_path_list,unlabel_train_label_list))


    label_train_path_list = all_image_paths[unlabeled_dataset_size:unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size]
    label_train_label_list = all_image_labels[unlabeled_dataset_size:unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size]
    label_train_dict = dict(zip(label_train_path_list,label_train_label_list))


    test_path_list = all_image_paths[unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size:]
    test_label_list = all_image_labels[unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size:]
    test_dict = dict(zip(test_path_list,test_label_list))


    train_dataset_path_list = all_image_paths[:unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size]
    train_dataset_label_list = all_image_labels[:unlabeled_dataset_size+labeled_dataset_size]
    train_dict = dict(zip(train_dataset_path_list,train_dataset_label_list))

    print('unlabel list: ',len(unlabel_train_dict),
    'labeled list: ', len(label_train_dict),
    'test list: ',len(test_dict),
    'train list: ',len(train_dict))

    steps_per_epoch = (unlabeled_dataset_size + labeled_dataset_size) // batch_size
    unlabeled_batch_size = unlabeled_dataset_size // steps_per_epoch
    labeled_batch_size = labeled_dataset_size // steps_per_epoch
    test_batch_size = test_dataset_size // steps_per_epoch

    print(f"batch size is {unlabeled_batch_size} (unlabeled) + {labeled_batch_size} (labeled)")

    unlabeled_train_dataset = make_datasets(list(unlabel_train_dict.keys()), list(unlabel_train_dict.values()),10 * unlabeled_batch_size,unlabeled_batch_size)

    labeled_train_dataset = make_datasets(list(label_train_dict.keys()), list(label_train_dict.values()),10 * labeled_batch_size,labeled_batch_size)

    test_dataset = make_datasets(list(test_dict.keys()), list(test_dict.values()),10*test_batch_size,test_batch_size)

    # train_dataset = make_datasets(list(train_dict.keys()), list(train_dict.values()),100,batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((unlabeled_train_dataset, labeled_train_dataset)).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return  unlabeled_train_dataset,labeled_train_dataset, test_dataset, train_dataset
```

I try to install numpy with corresponding cpu version, I also try to run it with 80gb gpu and more powerful cpu, the gpu-util on the machine still around 20-30%, and cpu is around 300%-400%.

Comment: You need to give details, what is the batch size? How complex is the model? Also "much faster" does not mean anything to us, you need to express them with numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The batch size is 500. The model is based on the simclr from this: https://keras.io/examples/vision/semisupervised_simclr/ I just replaced the data processing part and replace it with my own dataset.